# With tkinter text widget, how to use .insert so that it overwrites the entire text content?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building a restaurant menu using sql tables and tkinter which has buttons for Entrees, Mains and Desserts but it is stuck on the Entrees page for some reason:

```
#Setup - TKinter
import tkinter as tk
w = tk.Tk()
w.title("Interactive Restaurant Menu")
w.geometry("640x640")
w.resizable(False,False)
w['bg'] = 'black'

#Setup - SQL
import mysql.connector as mc
con = mc.connect(user = 'root',host = 'localhost', password = 'Cars!234',database = 'Zayan')
cur = con.cursor()

#Printing Menu Items
v = tk.Scrollbar( orient='vertical')
list = tk.Text(bg = 'black',font = ('Baskerville', 18),wrap = tk.WORD,yscrollcommand = v.set)
list.grid(column = 0,row = 2, columnspan = 4,padx = 20)

def getItem(ID, course):
    currentItem = []
    table_name = "Menu" + course
    query = "SELECT Item,Price,Description FROM {} WHERE ID = %s".format(table_name)
    cur.execute(query, (ID,))
    result = cur.fetchone()
    currentItem.append(result[0] + ' (' + str(result[1]) + '$)')
    currentItem.append(result[2])
    return currentItem

def printItems(course):
    cur.execute("select max(ID) from {}".format("Menu" + course))
    n = cur.fetchone()
    for i in range(1,n[0] + 1):
        list.insert(tk.END,'\n\n' + str(i) + "." + getItem(i,course)[0] + '\n' + getItem(i,course)[1])
    list.config(state='disabled',highlightthickness=0)

#Title And Buttons
head = tk.Label(text = "Menu",font = ("Garamond",40),bg = 'black')
head.grid(column = 0,row = 0,columnspan = 4, sticky = 'N', pady = 10)

app = tk.Button(text="Entrees",width = 12,height = 2,command=printItems('Entree'))
main = tk.Button(text="Mains",width = 12,height = 2,command=printItems('Main'))
des = tk.Button(text="Desserts",width = 12,height = 2)
deal = tk.Button(text="Deals",width = 12,height = 2)

app.grid(column = 0, row = 1,padx = 8)
main.grid(column = 1, row = 1,padx = 8)
des.grid(column = 2, row = 1,padx = 8)
deal.grid(column = 3, row = 1,padx = 8)
w.grid_columnconfigure((0,1,2,3), weight=1)

w.mainloop()
```

I think the problem lies with usage of .insert for the text widget. What can I use alternatively?

[image: Picture of Output]

Comment: In `printItems`, you're inserting your items at the end of the text widget (which you shouldn't name `list` btw). You should delete all lines first with `delete(start, end)` see the [doc](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html)

Answer (score 1):

> With tkinter text widget, how to use .insert so that it overwrites the entire text content?

Use it in combination with the `delete` method. First delete everything, then insert the new text.

Or, use the `replace` method which does exactly what it says. It replaces a range of text with some new text. You must give it both a starting and ending index of the range of text to delete, and also include the new text.